# JSON response field is undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

I followed the instructions here [Problem performing Ajax call from ASP.NET MVC2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371658/problem-performing-ajax-call-from-asp-net-mvc2-app), and read about JSON. I searched a lot but didn't find an answer. I use the following code:

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userName = $("#userName").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/PgAJAXTest',
    data: {
        q: 'Test1',
        s: 'Test2'
    },
    success: function (bbb) {
        alert(bbb.Val13);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
    }
});

</script>
```

ASP.NET MVC controller code is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PgAJAXTest(string q, string s)
    {
        var a = Json(new { Val13 = " TEST " }); 
        return a;
    }
```

The problem is that I get `"undefined"`.
If I change `alert(bbb.Val13);` to `alert(bbb);` I get `{"Val13":" TEST "}`

I suppose it has something to do with the controller not returning the JSON exactly in the format that JSON expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re getting a string response.

Use something like

```
success: function (bbb) {
    var response  = jQuery.parseJSON(bbb);
    alert(response.Val13);
}
```

Since you are using jQuery, you can use `jQuery.parseJSON` to parse the string.

Comment: Yes, this solved it Thanks! But how do I get a regular JSON response (so I can use bbb.Val13)?

Comment: Your response comes over http, so the result is a string by default. Either you parse the JSON yourself like above, or get jQuery to do it for you by setting `datatype: 'json'` while making the request.

Comment: @tereško yes, I agree using `JSON.parse` or `jQuery.parseJSON` is better. Updated my answer.

Comment: `eval` worked, but now, I changed it to `jQuery.parseJSON` and it doesn't. I'll just stay with the `eval`, thanks.

Comment: The `eval` row that worked for me (for future users) is: `var response = eval('(' + bbb+ ')');`

Comment: @Clangon do try `var response  = jQuery.parseJSON(bbb);`. I believe it should do a better job, now that I have read up about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `datatype: 'json'` to your JQuery AJAX request.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userName = $("#userName").val();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '/Home/PgAJAXTest',
    data: {
        q: 'Test1',
        s: 'Test2'
    },
    success: function (bbb) {
        alert(bbb.Val13);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: @Clangon Hmmm, is your code EXACTLY as posted? It sounds like the variable names used in the JS and the JSON object creation in the creation are different, even if they are different by a capital letter, it still counts.

Comment: @mattytommo Yes, that was the first thing I check and I checked that 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PgAJAXTest(string q, string s)
    {
        return Json(new { Val13 = " TEST " }); 
    }
```

Comment: That has the same problem. I only added the "a" variable so I can debug easier.

Comment: Yes sorry, Please seed mattytommo`s answer